# Moderator Strike

Tags: discussion, moderators

With seven of MSE's mods participating, wouldn't it be appropriate to draft a meta post with links to what is going on (the meta-meta post starting this, the statement of the participants, maybe a blog post or so written by a participant), by one of the other mods (not to take a stance, nothing long, just to share rather relevant news)?

Comment: [Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) to moderator strike on meta se

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing statements from other SE's, and would like to know what math.se mods are doing/thinking, either as mutually agreement or individually. As is usual in any large organization, my main concern is with my local community, and I would like to know how I can support the math.se mod specifically.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: You can sign the open letter [here](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) even if you are not a moderator.

Comment: Thanks, @MoisheKohanonstrike - A quick scan showed at least two math.se mods who I respect greatly signed, so okay.

Comment: Interesting though this "strike" might be to many, I see it as off-topic.  If one really wishes to have explanations from "striking moderators", the chatroom mechanism seems more appropriate than scattered discussion on per-site metas.  Math.SE doesn't seem to have any special connection to the dispute.  I'm inclined to vote to close as off-topic here but will wait to see if someone points out a nexus that I've overlooked.

Comment: At the time of writing, there are six moderators on MSE who have signed the [strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl): Alexander Gruber, Aloizio Macedo, Paramanand Singh, Pedro, TheSimpliFire, and Xander Henderson.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389812/1122837) answer under [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) on the main  SE meta has  links to *per-site meta discussions related to the strike*.

Comment: There was some moderator discussion about whether or not to write a separate post here. But I'll note that every active MathSE moderator has either signed the letter or noted some dissatisfaction. We've also talked about some other planned SE policy changes/decisions that haven't yet been made public.

Comment: I'd post one, but I'm striking. As far as what is specific to Mathematics, one of the not-yet-public planned policy changes would affect us disproportionately more than other sites, and we are fighting that, too, for you, behind the scenes. The rest of our reasons align tightly with the [demand letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), which we encourage those who wish to join the strike to sign as well.

Comment: Thank you for updating the "participating" count in the post. Between that, and the links to the Meta post and the letter, I think this post brings enough information into our math.se meta for anyone who might care to learn about the strike, i.e. I don't think a separate, new post is required.

Comment: I can't see anything about how long the strike will last. Is it a single day, 5 June, or on-going?

Comment: @PeterPhipps: It is ongoing. In the [moderation strike post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) on Meta Stack Exchange, it states that the strike will not end until a list of conditions have been met, including the retraction of the new AI policy.

Comment: Why would this post be closed if it is the older one?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Perhaps because the other one was posted by a mod, so it carries more weight and may have better visibility. It is the first site-level strike post that I see *Featured on Meta* now.

Answer (score 29):

To save people tracking stuff down, here is part the [strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) that could be useful to non-moderators:

---

#### I am not a moderator on any stack exchange site, how can I help?

Even if you are not a moderator you can participate in the strike by:

- Not voting on posts
- Not submitting edits
- Not reviewing in the review queues
- Not commenting
- Not flagging posts

DO NOT engage in vandalism. We're abstaining from moderation- not trying to be actively destructive.

- DO NOT purposefully submit AI-generated answers during the strike. While we will not be removing them during the strike you may be suspended afterwards. We anticipate plenty will get posted anyway without purposefully submitting more.
- DO NOT upvote spam, AI generated posts, or other low quality posts. Do not downvote good posts. That is just disrespectful, better to not vote at all.
- DO NOT be rude to stack exchange employees, those who choose not to strike, or anyone else.

Comment: Heh, now I'm wondering whether I should upvote this post in agreement.