# Is flag handling backlogged?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderators

I currently have 7 unhandled comment flags, including two I raised back in May. I also have one unhandled post flag from June 13.

Is there a technical issue here that is causing flags to get lost?  Or is does the moderator team overwhelmed, and needs to be expanded?

Comment: Maybe it could be related to the moderation strike. [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/)

Comment: Right, I forgot!  [General Moderation Strike: Mathematics StackExchange moderators are participating](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35765/25554)

Comment: @MJD you can mark as duplicate if you wish.

Answer (score 6):

I was reminded by a comment that at least 7 of the 10 Math SE moderators have been on a protest strike since June 5.

[General Moderation Strike: Mathematics StackExchange moderators are participating](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35765/25554)

Comment: Yes. It is quite backlogged.