# Moderation Strike Resolution

Tags: discussion, moderation

As many of you likely already know, moderators across the SE network have been engaged in a work stoppage since early June, for a number of reasons, which are outlined in the main meta post [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/).  Nearly all of the Math SE moderators signed the [strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), and have been abstaining from moderation for the last two months.

As of Wednesday, [Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/), negotiations between StackExchange and the moderators' elected representatives have concluded.  Further discussion can be found at [Moderation strike: Conclusion and the way forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392032/). Because moderators on the SE network are a loose collection of individuals, the choice to return to moderation duty is up to each individual.

After discussion, the Mathematics SE moderation team has determined that the negotiated settlement is acceptable enough, and that we will be returning to actively moderating the site.  Please be patient as we work to catch up with the backlog of flags.

Comment: Know that a lot of us users greatly appreciate everything you and the other moderators do.

Comment: I was wondering when we were going to hear from y'all, but August is a hell of a month to get hold of academics. Thanks to you all, for this update, for sticking together to improve things, and for everything you do day-to-day.

Comment: Additionally, I remember it being mentioned that there were some math.SE-specific issues that you hoped to raise. I don't know what they were, or if they were addressed. I also don't know if it would be profitable to talk publicly about them now. But I am curious, and would like info about them, if y'all consider it appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanZ We were concerned that the issue referred to in the negotiations as the "second shoe" would have disproportionately affected math.se. I can't elaborate on what it was or why it would have affected us more than others, but if that change does occur, it will be weakened and reversible. I am no longer concerned about it. We got what we wanted, there.

Comment: I had wondered if we would hit 1000 unresolved flags, but we did not.

Comment: @davidlowryduda - Some of us considered flagging as a moderation action, even when done by non-moderators, and stopped doing it during the strike. I guess it might have been more impressive if we'd flagged like normal?